# Hide or show element with checkbox selection in renderless React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to know how to show or hide a div depending on my checkbox selection. I know there's a similar thread about this ([how to hide or show a div if checkbox is selected in React JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36134236/how-to-hide-or-show-a-div-if-checkbox-is-selected-in-react-js))

But I'm having an renderless React app. So how do I do it without the render() method?

My code so far:

The checkbox:

```
<div number-input id="vacationPercentageSwitch" class="form-group col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-8" style={{ marginLeft: "38px" }}>
    <div number-input id="vacationPercentageSwitchDiv" class="form-group col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-8" style={{ marginBottom: "10px" }}>
        <label htmlFor="inputVacationPercentage" className="switch switch-default">
        <input id="inputVacationPercentage" type="checkbox" />
        <span><span></span></span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

The content I want to toggle:

```
<div number-input id="qualificationYearDropdown" class="form-group col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-8">
    <label for="qualificationYearOptions"><span class="requiredAsterisk"></span></label>
    <select id="qualificationYear" class="form-control">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: If you're not rendering anything then nothing will be shown. What do you mean "renderless React app"?

Comment: I might got it all wrong.. In my Jsx-file I have the following:

export const checkBoxtest = ({ context }) => {

return (


my code
);
};

Ergo, no render method like in the linked example. I thought you only needed render method in a class that extends React.Component

Comment: In a functional component, the whole component is the render method. Whatever you return from the component gets rendered. I will post an answer below.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Guess he means Functional Component (stateless)

You need to use `useState` Hook

> Hooks are a new addition in React 16.8. They let you use state and other React features without writing a class. [Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

Also, Please note that you shouldn't mix `class` with `className` In Jsx you should use `className` only.

Please follow this example:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";


const App = () => {
 // initial value is `false`
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

  const handleChange = () => {
    // Change state to the opposite (to ture) when checkbox changes
    setChecked(!checked);
  };

  return (
    <div className="conditional-checkbox">
      <label
        htmlFor="inputVacationPercentage"
        className="switch switch-default"
      >
        Checkbox
      </label>
      <input
        id="inputVacationPercentage"
        type="checkbox"
        checked={checked}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />

      { /* Inline conditional if checked state is `true` will show the div, otherwise, it won't */ }

      { checked && (
        <div
          number-input
          id="qualificationYearDropdown"
          class="form-group col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-8"
        >
          <label for="qualificationYearOptions">
            <span class="requiredAsterisk" />
          </label>
          <select id="qualificationYear" class="form-control">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      )}

    </div>
  );
};
```

Learn more about [Inline If and Logical && Operator](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator)

See full example [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/functional-checkbox-component-1711z)

Comment: Oh thank you! That really helped! I mark this as answer to my question

Answer (score 0):

In the `Component` class add:

1) *isChecked* to *state*. What I did is to create a *CheckBoxModel* class and add to it all kinds of properties that I what to use later, e.g. *isChecked*, *isActive*, *isHidden*, etc.

```
class CheckBoxModel {
  constructor(id, text) {
    this.id = id;
    this.text = text;
    this.isActive = true;
    this.isVisible = false;
  }
}
```

2) An array of the *CheckBoxModel* in the *state*:

```
this.state = {
   checkboxes:[],
}
```

Don't forget to populate this array with *CheckboxModel*s.

3) Add function to find the *CheckBox* index in the array of checkboxes:

```
getTaskIndexInArrayById(checkBoxId, checkboxes) {
   for (let index = 0; index < checkboxes.length; index++) {
      if (checkboxes[index].id === checkBoxId) {
         return index;
      }
   }
   return -1; // Not Found
}
```

4) Add a function to handle the *CheckBox* is *OnChange* event:

```
onCheckBoxChanged(event) {
   checkBoxId = item.currentTarget.id;
   const {attributes } = event.currentTarget;
   let ( checkboxes } = this.state;
   checkboxIndex = this.getCheckBoxIndexById(checkBoxId, checkboxes);
   if (checkboxIndex !== -1) {
      checkboxes[checkboxIndex].isChecked = !checkboxes[checkboxIndex].isChecked;
      if (checkboxes[checkboxIndex].isChecked) {
         // Your code for when checkbox got checked
      } else {
         // Your code for when checkbox got unchecked
      }
      this.setState({ checkboxes });
   }
}
```

5) Add *OnChange* to your checkbox to capture checked/unchecked changes:

```
<input id="inputVacationPercentage" type="checkbox" onChange={(event) => this.onCheckBoxChanged(event)} />
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a functional component, so you need to use the `useState` hook if you want to hold state inside it. You should read up on hooks https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html. They're incredibly useful.

Your component should look something like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const MyComponent = () => {
    const [isContentVisible, setIsContentVisible] = useState(false)

    return (
        <>
            <div
                number-input
                id="vacationPercentageSwitch"
                class="form-group col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-8"
                style={{ marginLeft: '38px' }}
            >
                <div
                    number-input
                    id="vacationPercentageSwitchDiv"
                    class="form-group col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-8"
                    style={{ marginBottom: '10px' }}
                >
                    <label
                        htmlFor="inputVacationPercentage"
                        className="switch switch-default"
                    >
                        <input
                            id="inputVacationPercentage"
                            type="checkbox"
                            checked={isContentVisible}
                            onChange={() => setIsContentVisible(prev => !prev)}
                        />
                        <span>
                            <span></span>
                        </span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            {isContentVisible && (
                <div
                    number-input
                    id="qualificationYearDropdown"
                    class="form-group col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-8"
                >
                    <label for="qualificationYearOptions">
                        <span class="requiredAsterisk"></span>
                    </label>
                    <select id="qualificationYear" class="form-control">
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            )}
        </>
    )
}
```

The content will be rendered conditionally on the value of `isContentVisible` which is controlled using the checkbox.